# Python/subprocess : reading output from batch file fails

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, output

Let me explain the problem : I got a batch file, that requires admin permissions. And I want to start this batch file from python, so I made a shortcut of it, and I run this shortcut with python, and it works fine with :

```py
os.startfile(r"C:/MyBatchShortcut.lnk")
```

But now I want to improve it : I would like to read the output from the batch to display the informations into my python application. So instead of os.startfile(), I started using subprocess.Popen(). I made a test with another (way more simple) batch file, and it gives :

```py
import subprocess
output= subprocess.Popen(
    (r"C:/AnotherBatchShortcut.lnk"),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout
for line in output:
    print(line)
output.close()
```

And I can get the output, no problem. BUT, and there the magic happens, when I try with the good batch, all I get as output is :

```py
^C
>>>
```

That's all... Here is the batch file :

```
@echo off
cd C:/
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pause
set count=1
if exist testproxy.txt.tmp del "testproxy.txt.tmp" /s /f /q>NUL
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (testproxy.txt) do (
if !count! equ 1 (
   set "TIMER=%%a"
   )
set /a count+=1
)
setlocal
set file=testproxy.txt
set lineToDelete=1
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%file%" ^|findstr /bv "%lineToDelete%:"') do echo/%%b) > "%file%.tmp
move /y "%file%" "%file%">NUL
:loop
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (testproxy.txt.tmp) do (
   netsh winhttp set proxy %%A
   timeout %TIMER%
)
goto :loop
```

So I use setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion, @echo off at the beginning, maybe there is the problem ? Or is it with the shell=True in the python script, because when I set it to false it doesn't work even with the simple one ? Maybe the admin permissions requirement makes the bug ? I don't know, and if you could help me, I would be very happy ^^'

Comment: You're running a batch file which has a never ending loop which you're clearly force closing using CTRL+C. If you don't want that then either get rid of the never ending loop, or find another way of quitting the batch file.

Comment: Ok thanks ! But what do you mean with CTRL + C ? I don't use that, my program runs and when I don't want it to run anymore I close it...

Comment: Whatever method you're currently using to close it, is issuing `[CTRL]`+`[C]`, which is being displayed in your provided output, _(as `^C`)_.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that... Thanks again ! I'll try to fix it with what you told me ^^